# Windev: Looking for suggestions on how to decrypt a string to a zip file

Tags: windev

I am consuming a web service that answers the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
                <ns0:getStatusCdrResponse xmlns:ns0="http://service.sunat.gob.pe">
                        <statusCdr>
                                <content>UEsDBBQACAgIABqiRFUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiAAAAUi0yMDU1NDA2MDQ5OS0wMS1GMDA1LTAwMDAwMDc2LnhtbLVZW3OqShZ+n19h5TxmJ1wU1FSSqW5uooByVah5QUBEuQko6K+fRqMx+2TX7D01kzykWevrdfnWopvuvP6zSeLOISjKKEvfHohn/KETpF7mR2n49mAa/NPg4Z/v/3h1ixeQ53HkuRUCakGZZ2kZdNDktHx72BfpS+aWUfmSuklQvpR54EWrD/DLfhm/lN46SNyXpvRfxPSQRV7wRD5cpr+4xR9a+CaST2tBU/2hOSZLkizlmipIWxbQIzIZpFX5adRbev+VUYjg3rcG3f/OIAjDIgjdKvjOqI9Ksa6q/AXD6rp+rrvPWRFiJI7jGD7EEMYvo/CvK7rM3PyGvzgqn5GqlZ8ntgMsSA9BnOUBdnOCnN+mBU0ZV2dwKy6f3NR/qiKUy83JNc9yn7rVL/PMg2J/n6zeor/Llbgabn6VK4EtZEk/m7pikZWgyb8JGin2sVs8IW0RlG3xy4f3V9RBLyaUbg1RXtv8G91Fctc7KRpV7696FKIM9sXtFfmNuqDXrJ0W+GK6yt7/0em8Mm6apYinODqduZKDap35HRCHWRFV6+SXFBB4axbl5T15RC/9a47QbQO1HD5gZ9u3CH/bKN67xvqUZEXwV1G6T+XapQjyw6QWrIICrR5Bx9TEli4kRGKjcNNylRVJeRHci/6j2y8UXZvRfyqv0V9c/6HR3yEIGcR+jvyVjcKgrH6TsS+hI6KIm+GLGcuN98H7kgXDtOqDcUwMvYmaaZN5QcuczSX22yt2j2wpxm4co27BvrbLfVEvM2ZA2BNq1e2RiafCrWM6dEly41jf4956BwbxspGd46nXT214MgqGSw1Lb4zFptlPpLm86J9O/e4qHhA9vFhuhHTOprNhdpwVzt4hhjpL73rUrOBqoUsT4k7Fa2Im4P19PCFmyjruTiMPx2IDmHpIpGJuVnyxw/JGPeVDsysNi6M46NEHNZtgXiStJkumcXd0PXPx5WIOlzPJxXCGrSjbLvOFMdpzyqHxmP6MThMerJeWuQ0wzCHYDIMn1faY6rBZbaSRZpQEMHbBuHQcSS+SbaaT+aOOzbZOQfTZfrFgGHHamxYpqawZF8zVRbjZ9/fTwN9TI0FJ60WX9vnHMqmonlYcRA0ugogaUTNO6A+BD97eLszfEf06CY7nMrwuKHzIupV7GTFBUV1WuuBdFkUxNhgGpmQIahGCUBwburp1FrTFc4dGBrjA6DtBF5ddVuUgU5sAzYHihpNksBUAYXJwLTMmZzasASQYKhYyIkOuGRsmdyfzbrKZAfoXWSkrIyV2dLjxF+OjM6dwUeC3zmgce105tBdq6Hf9rpQo6+XcOjpJfFzOub1NDisphbFE3rCNzIL91eYY51mRU6BhWrq2jXXkMzQ5S6+pLFRxS7e4WNBNBWrc0BAZPJQ3oFE2nClD8ZKPJktIRigb+ySzIq6wXiNsgH22L3AyZ1KmGUNeMsRaMWxSPoGjwqpdWQf1KLRZS1UnLPRZ1SR4c+uMzS0BRR7yZjl1RV7eqzrFShuulpne2R+o61Q1ZRQbr2jWWNCtsaLqUNUsiU0iyCKZqZvOGOk5g5BDSQdHmeVIGfYWrCGi8baRT9xJNgAuE1krw8+yzU1Wh6ttI57AGobb3XobCcMah4zKzXmB2LpznvZIHnhda4843zvkMGr5lU2untXnfFiWXRuWhXLYxlOL6YXGlmelCHKaDqHGWxA9GyK/DTXODFVTU3STGpuEpqumMjbwXmjx47EaW6Zqob8Gp8igvHBd15zBxQqS3fhnQC2dZTqoxI+e4VmgX+vLnMRaNuQ25+PUMAnZ8GpFPccpsQw19roK4czV0E63v+D0wp/IQKge4Zc6yWqvZsFHDYFlWCYFLfZvvV6HIRf9/G4A1QSgJ0K2Bq1+AjL0PqlMt8QwaWkSzFxXdCHwOZ2E2nQshfxQn0a5ovhgiREjsTmc9v18ZbLUQmUnuafVDhlhxEGEg4OVWYb+WPU2TBZmJJFtSbsZ1kXKcM5GPGwGhZna+gqS2S7vwYqYRgM8qC2hnI0jva82qZzWClafCpuheSUa7jDjyO/yMsfLtQWocLKe6uZp5RSaQ0je1KmJIpG8rqfRoKD3xhSPWJoT2RVG8dFiXZvObMVZbmKSi0kU6hOGUgKti/Ub/JEc2qZOD8JBSQ82oHYcTE2qXTbA1J1SVt2JW5AyDejSx/LuQdjb2sL3c2tmadZiqimiTLOLYTmpV6UprXbJyI7NZm+nx2a7myirXLWxLTnVHtllu8QAIGzCUDqi9Yjpb4Dc9sdIQ/LVgAMbAGRwfr98tuYgVqvoPRMFVFz/jNNNjt8AE6LPORhyPFQ9FoS2OKlt1BTmCNRqPWp7SsOnENocz6FNz1+m84mUK4PZZtVfJCvDz6otoGRRUO7soJqjVmXho8yrAsOgPldNHp4As96iDXqk1ag6h1+ua6QSe6l2QmvbZkHe6/mVJ1hH3xpunMUYd+dObqP1b9mVq/P6FVEbL1Xr8V0OMhAEIVnj/gjQ0nF4sLtK/Z1PGQ7OPIm1asvQBTyb7x1tk1qVtB0cu36+aI7L1aDu2XaKcg0vPA+40Anr0DFrfQKFjNMF9dPXxktqZJuvUKyJuxhXtk5tliR+sOfK6ovcGtZoTCwueecoro091w7eET+/oyje45KF44wLQs12WHek4R6bHRBPSM79L330L3lxnM/CY6hplSPE6yBV1upIIZYJj0uJf7AjqnZczZX5sLE2EPVP1tadA7Ywkta9Ccs5X9fr43mNNDSzkdGYNziLRWvhzNjG7IeONyyoa5bS7hHQ3HJo/fR5I9Z48wihZWkzw+RN3crP+5UM63OtEMqS4RRycxSf8E1Nr3XSwa1OoSMK7LkfVRja3n60BkdgMDA0QH7XvwzQbP/M80hua1kvySa3u9vvuK4tcPfOhGKtg0b4uscOznuCiVuy0Y7NhlfRvmDgFOLnotNMQjW3ltGuz2h/gCLHjzS0x2oW2hMtyzRwAiJ7LtpXZuYJKPd7GFBLHoApA0IOrGtPO4wdOC9tv9/0i2m+HFNh7Hq09Di3tcic7/w1I6SZdZhPzK6HEXDWbBQ4F0zZbBroLuxFiTdT6XSM4c6fCosGd6OhtO3lC8LbceSSiev4OC2aWl3ZtCsdRqE4mRK7JOpCqieEizxMd/uDkTJWUJDs4zrkhKhXdmlGmg9JMR+Ep0fKFAUzgodR/6iopGjtN7a0XDuQHIly5JvmYLqTd1Yp6r1RbRiFs4KPoj80uTXtm164mEnbYDplPK5RVvM1YZ8erUweQ6eq9boXaTU7IneHYr8Zr5uu5tCngVk8cqFvH7uSUz8WVGInwa7fV6fHucsRopkthz6/GLKGXvibDdoNDqlEeFt75wdV5lH1hpw7VdZvesVySLkEvpayxSroFcqSTlmjNMoFOTuSGMPR9rAvjRK7prfRYaAuXX2ti5tSsuBBq3NfmpPJGMZFmpwoxWIOs9wdqztKntPHzF0eVg1j1k0Wkjtht9n5G8cuTzjqjX2PB7aLLQ540C0zp+G0sqRDYzp79MTJktzvbA1iXaPg9OkhWzNYCudipc9HdD/SKF7W6obEdUZhBu4qm63XNhcK5KTfWKVs94P5kkmPGGRmh1MSLGcCwW0LrLbX+bI90Lm1NtBoqZ6Eie3OuiJrAdVl1eFeZhsOz6TDZEam/tyhOYEu4caIVgCbD8aT0u5i8xqrabenHaTNI0PV0E8e7UWW6YI0d07KbF2jj/Wfv8TPn+ZiWe6DQg+KyI3vJYqbBO+M8vYAmA4DZE7jRU0GnRmn/Yvp/msIOgynoe8vkQHsVO88dUicoB9+dKZvD9+i9WfwzDwjAPlMPfeeh/03xdBm3BOJUzTdxcler/+jU56jUPbJMijevmim5h8HYr6VQdDx9gU6JlYd1/fbq42OW3Xa06mHsitWUZG4z16WPOcB9gH40ZHeJFEGPzq68TFg3mbchbw7Zs5M6XfxvhM9sovj6ARI9KkehXcHg26fJi4TvwDvbV15xz7PS9jtDDUrsjwroyp7Z/ZJHged/Cp4xT51r1pwyDzXa29hPnDFTdIelG/aV0OXrpCqjNG5Hj2/ck0eFReAknXWbic4C3zk5E51d9RD4+8ve7C/3wr9TVS+v3pLrxVZl8tWkX0nn/FX7G/SM47Zl1WWfFz7ICFxhf6sOKNbWzhJEjhB9obUoE9+gG/6lnO2bf0W9kTgT3jvA3HTfAKNKGmBL0Tvherewc7yM+x66/qtyS/KL/CbYfpm+IvqFdXr5Y7ujxRaCdrggHGX1A2YFceZW1THi+w8FH1Uldv94h1DRBf9kkOK+jSE/XrWVXFp+3bCeXQXyUWD/YTEfhUc+qyNKje+JQiqyvXWybmFWn3bK0Xqxp9XPJeW0cT3v37ioJVdHH0zCftPzrCfeW4fg9QPiv8Pldi3DrTAC6LDH/ikqB5O473h8Ld9fuOCzbx9y8K18a6x3J7OTfnBJXLB4zj1hJ9/+vS1Zz/VX/qbyfzgHf/a2GfZGcUGpVdE+Tk8ye3wrofYdzspCqfIOl/8/GiXozLys47rBXnl+u7F6L2Ja4b3aXwm96WDvk/jxt93sy7kRXmE5L9ZIBrtaTQ+GAy7OIX/SYm+eMG+LxL2/T+g3v8NUEsHCAtcqf2ODQAAwBoAAFBLAQIUABQACAgIABqiRFULXKn9jg0AAMAaAAAiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABSLTIwNTU0MDYwNDk5LTAxLUYwMDUtMDAwMDAwNzYueG1sUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAUAAAAN4NAAAAAA==</content>
                                <statusCode>0004</statusCode>
                                <statusMessage>La constancia existe</statusMessage>
                        </statusCdr>
                </ns0:getStatusCdrResponse>
        </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The `<content>` is supposed to be a ZIP file, unfortunately I have no idea how to convert those characters to a ZIP, any suggestions on windev options I can use.

Use WINDEV 21.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to decode "content" to file.

```
bufZip is buffer = Decode(content,encodeBASE64)

fsavebuffer("c:\your folder\file.zip",bufZip)
```

Comment: Thanks.

Although in version 21 there is no "Decode" function... it helped me to find its equivalent and it was solved.

```
bufZip is Buffer = Uncrypt(content,"",cryptAnsi,encodeBASE64)
   
fSaveBuffer("c:\your folder\file.zip",bufZip)
```